# cypress each method get a child elements href

Tags: cypress

I'm using an each method in cypress to find a list of li elements.
What I'm after is to find a child inside the li and test its href value.
The child is an a tag.

Here is what I have so far:

```
  it("should have ..... ", () => {
    cy.get("ul > li")
      .each((el, index, list) => {
        expect(el.text()).to.be.oneOf(["hello", "world"]);
        const a = cy.wrap(el).find("a");
        expect(a.attr("href")).to.be.oneOf(["/hello", "/world"]);
      })
      .then((list) => {
        expect(list).to.have.length(2);
      });
  });
```

Error:  **a.attr is not a function**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wrap the `el`. If you do, it becomes a Cypress command which is always async.

You would have to do

```js
cy.wrap(el).find("a").then(a => {
  expect(a.attr("href")).to.be.oneOf(["/hello", "/world"]);
})
```

But find works for jQuery as well.

```js
const a = el.find("a")
expect(a.attr("href")).to.be.oneOf(["/hello", "/world"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're storing the results of a Cypress (Promise-like) `Chainable`. Also using an `expect` inside `each` won't benefit from the retry-ability provided by `should`.

```
it("should have ..... ", () => {
    cy.get("ul > li")
      .should("have.length", 2)
      .each(($el) => {
        cy.wrap($el)
          .invoke("text")
          .should("be.oneOf", ["hello", "world"])
        
        cy.wrap($el)
          .find("a")
          .invoke("attr", "href")
          .should("be.oneOf", ["/hello", "/world"])      
      });
 });
```